# Выборка из двух таблиц через JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, алгоритм

Сижу 2 часа, не могу разобраться как получить данные из двух таблиц... всегда спасала конструкция вида `... LEFT JOIN table2 USING(id) ...`. Но не в этот раз:

Есть 2 таблицы:

table1:

```
| sid | aid | foo1
|  1  |  1  | bar1
|  1  |  1  | bar1
|  1  |  1  | bar1
|  1  |  1  | bar1
|  1  |  1  | bar1
|  1  |  2  | bar11
|  1  |  2  | bar11
|  1  |  2  | bar11
```

table2:

```
| sid | aid | foo2
|  1  |  1  | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar2
|  1  |  2  | bar22
|  1  |  2  | bar22
|  1  |  2  | bar22
```

связывающие поля - `sid` и `aid`

Запрос:

```
SELECT table1.foo1, table2.foo2 FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN table2 USING(sid, aid) WHERE sid = 1 AND aid = 1
```

Ожидание:

```
| sid | aid | foo1 | foo2
|  1  |  1  | bar1 | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar1 | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar1 | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar1 | bar2
|  1  |  1  | bar1 | bar2
```

вместо этого получаю много повторяющихся строк... помогите составить запрос

Comment: лучше забудьте про синтаксис using, он же непонятен и порождает массу ошибок. пишите явно что чему равно `ON table1.sid=table2.sid and table1.aid=table2.aid` правда это вам вряд ли поможет. У вас в обоих таблицах с aid,sid=1,1 много записей, значит рузультирующих строк будет произведение количеств таких записей в исходных таблицах

Comment: Есть такая штука DISTINCT http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=1232

Answer (score 1):

Если не вдаваться в странности представленной структуры, то:

```
select distinct table1.sid, table1.aid, table1.foo1, table2.foo2 
from table1, table2
where table1.aid = table2.aid 
  and table1.sid = table2.sid 
  and table1.sid = 1 
  and table1.aid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.foo1, t2.foo2
from table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.sid=t2.sid and t1.aid=t2.aid
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно больше почитать про нормализацию запросов сикивела.
Как написал коллега выше есть обычный джойн (который скорее всего вам и нужен).
А LEFT JOIN соединяет таблицы таким образом, что при отсуствии совпадений с основной таблицей, в присоединяемой таблице будут пустые места.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*, foo2 FROM `table1` JOIN 
(select distinct * from table2) X 
USING(sid, aid) WHERE table1.sid = 1 AND table1.aid = 1
```